# How do I make a conditional statement for Switch statement

Tags: powershell

I need to make a conditional statement so that:

```
'.txt' { Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-ResourcePath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), - " /un", $policy.FullName, " /q")}
```

It is based on both `.txt` and the filename of `"xyz.txt"`.  I am struggling to get this to work, though.  Code below without additional condition of `filename = xyz.txt`

```
function Import-GpoSettings{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Imports group policy files. 
.DESCRIPTION
    Applies DISA/ESS specific group policies.
.PARAMETER
    Resource path to find pol files.
.PARAMETER
    MatchString finds pol files that includes this string in the file name.
#>
    Param (
        [string] $Resource,
        [string] $MatchString
    )
    
    $policies = Get-ChildItem (Get-ResourcePath $Resource) | Where-Object Extension -in '.txt', '.inf', '.csv' | Where-Object Name -match $matchString

    ForEach ($policy in $policies) {
        [string] $currentPolicy = $policy.BaseName
        Write-HostAndLog "`t Applying standard $currentPolicy policy settings.`n"
        switch ($policy.Extension) {
            '.txt' { Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-ResourcePath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), - " /un", $policy.FullName, " /q")}
            '.txt' { Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-ResourcePath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), " /t", $policy.FullName, " /q")}
            '.inf' { Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-ResourcePath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), " /s", $policy.FullName, " /q")}
            '.csv' { Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-resourcepath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), " /a", $policy.FullName, " /q")}
            Default { }
        }

    }

}#endFunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `switch` statement condition to *match* two or more conditions, you can use the syntax described in the [**MS Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) for this [language keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2#switch) using a [scriptblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2):

[image: about_Switch]

It's also worth noting that the `switch` can do the looping for you, so technically you don't need `foreach` in this case. You can also add the condition for *matching extensions* and testing if the file name matches `$matchString` in the `switch` itself, so this can also be removed:

```
Where-Object Extension -in '.txt', '.inf', '.csv' | Where-Object Name -match $matchString
```

Lastly, you will notice the use of [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.2) on each of the *action scriptblocks*, this is because a `switch` evaluates all conditions before going to the next element unless we add control flows.

```
switch(Get-ChildItem (Get-ResourcePath $Resource)) {
    # if the filename doesn't match, just got to the next item,
    # below conditions will not be evaluated
    { $_.Name -notmatch $matchString } { continue }

    # this conditions is always exectued
    { $true } {
        Write-HostAndLog ("`t Applying standard {0} policy settings.`n" -f $_.BaseName)
    }

    # this is the condition that evaluates the question being asked,
    # extension is `.txt` and file name is `xyz.txt`
    { $_.Extension -eq '.txt' -and $_.Name -eq 'xyz.txt' } {
        # => code here for this condition!
        continue
    }

    {$_.Extension -eq '.txt' } {
        Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-ResourcePath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), - " /un", $_.FullName, " /q")
        continue
    }

    { $_.Extension -eq '.inf' } {
        Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-ResourcePath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), " /s", $_.FullName, " /q")
        continue
    }
    
    { $_.Extension -eq '.csv' } {
        Invoke-CommandAndLog @((Get-resourcepath "UtilityModules\LGPO.exe"), " /a", $_.FullName, " /q")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am new to learning powershell, and appreciate the help!